# Is there a way to save a different instance of an activity for each date selected in calendar view?

Tags: android, android-listview, calendarview

I just started Android development about a week ago. I'm trying to create a Todo list app where I have a different list for every day that I select. Is there a way to create multiple instances of an activity so I can have a separate list for each day?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear,
You can have the same Activity with a ListView, but different data for each day.